# Android onBackPressed not triggering when SearchView is active

Tags: android, searchview, onbackpressed

I have two search views in my app one below the other. When I expand two search views and try to close the SearchViews by click on the device back button. Then the cursor is moving from the second search view to the first and first search view to the second always. But `onBackPressed` is not triggering at all.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (!searchViewOne.isIconified) { // It is not triggering here on back press
         // TODO something here
        }
}
```

> Problem: `onBackPressed` not triggering when SearchViews are active

> Expectation: Want to close both the SearchViews `onBackPressed`

Note: This is only happening in Android OS 6.0 (API <= 23) and below. Above 6.0 it is working as expected.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: how are you triggering the event onbackpress?

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri Updated my question

Comment: how about use onActionViewCollapsed();? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView#onActionViewCollapsed()

Comment: @ST The issue is when the user clicks on the device back button. It will not work in this case

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it by making `isFocusable` to `false` in init search views.

```
searchViewOne.isFocusable = false
searchViewTwo.isFocusable = false
```

Now `onBackPress` is triggered and the problem got solved.